Sending email without any triggers or user actions
Scenario here is SharePoint should send email every month or year on a set date for a particular document library item to set of email groups. Example: Reminder email to higher officials saying election should be conducted to select officers. This should happen every year on a particular date.
Here there is no user interaction happen for that document library from SharePoint UI or user perspective. How to achieve this in latest SharePoint 365?

Add-ons - not supported
Web part - not required as we don't want to show any custom stuffs in UI
CSOM code - can write logic in C# or JavaScript and achieve it. But, how to host the code and how it works?

Please suggest with detailed steps.

Which Microsoft 365 (Office 365) license you have in your company? Do you have access & allowed to use "Power Automate" in your company?
